# Discord.Net user information command won't work for other users

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

Hi I am developing a Discord Bot using the Discord.Net library. The issue I am having is I cannot get the user information for other users in the Discord server. It will only return the information for me or the bot. If I try to make return information for other users in the server then it will throw the following exception "ObjectNotFound: User not found." Which is weird as the users I am mentioning are in the server.

```
        [Command("info")]
        public async Task Info(SocketUser i)
        {

            EmbedBuilder e = new EmbedBuilder();
            e.Title = "Information for " + i.Username;
            e.AddField("Join Date", i.CreatedAt);
            e.AddField("Current User Status", i.Status);
            e.AddField("User ID", i.Id);
            e.AddField("Avatar ID", i.AvatarId);
            e.AddField("Username", i.Username);
            e.AddField("Username Number ID / Discriminator", i.Discriminator);
            e.AddField("Full Username", i.Username + "#" + i.Discriminator);
            e.AddField("Is Bot?", i.IsBot);
            e.AddField("Is Webhook?", i.IsWebhook);

            e.ThumbnailUrl = i.GetAvatarUrl();


            await ReplyAsync("", false, e.Build());
        }
```

Photos:

Me mentioning myself in the bot and it working: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qb2Bh.jpg

Me mentioning my friend and it returning the error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Frzcs.jpg

Comment: You need to enable member intents in the Discord Bot Portal and specify the intent in you DiscordSocketConfig

Comment: @Anu6is thank you that did the trick! I don’t think I had to specify the intent with the “DiscordSocketConfig” unles I already did so in a previous build.

Comment: You have to from version 3.0 up. If you are on an older version of DNet it's not required as it uses the older Discord Gateway version.